# How to make a python function from another python file run as an independent process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So what i want to do this this, assume 2 python files A.py and B.py.

A.py

---

```
import B

some_code

.

.

.


function_of_B.py()

rest_of_the_code
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the `rest_of_the_code` waits for `function_of_B.py()` to finish executing, what I want is for `function_of_B.py()` to execute in paralell or independent of A.py such that `rest_of_the_code` can run without waiting for `function_of_B.py()` to finish.

Comment: I would suggest preparing a batch file (file.bat) with its content being " ````python pythonfile.py```` ".  Later, simple double-click on the same batch file will run the code ````pythonfile.py```` in python.

Comment: So, I can just run the .bat with some python code instead of double-click. Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: Does the ``rest_of_the_code`` in any way depend on what ``function_of_B`` is doing? Does it need to share memory with it?

Comment: No, no common variables or anything, reads some text files

Answer (score 1):

Use multithreading:

```
import B
import threading

some_code

threading.Thread(target=B.function_of_B).start()

rest_of_the_code
```

you can use :

```
print("this thread executed by",threading.current_thread().getName())
```

to get current thread name in B.py and A.py